# libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04, dependencies

[image: y]

i have the booting stuck on /dev/sda2 clean
so i tried the following steps:

1. Ctrl + Alt + F2 OR F3
2. login with my account
3. `sudo apt-get update` ✅
4. `sudo apt-get upgrade` ❌

(4) shows error E: unmet dependence and to solve it, it shows `apt -fix-broken install`

when i ran the `apt -fix-broken install` this error shows :

(libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director)

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libglib2.0-bin`. The FFI issue looks strange, as this library was available for 19.10. Do you really run 20.04 LTS?

Comment: @N0rbert thx for the reply, unfortunately, it shows the same Error (E: unmet Dependencies)  The Broken package  is <libglib2.0.0>

Comment: Could you please say all the history? How did you went to this situation? Did you have 16.04 LTS previously installed? What is your current Ubuntu version? Which version do you have in /etc/apt/sources.list? Can you access this system via SSH?

Comment: @N0rbert, the start point to this when I was installing a program, one of its dependencies were `libglib2.0.0` for some strange reason it broke during the installation so I restarted my machine cuz of a lock of (dpkg) :|  when I started the machine it stuck on the booting (/dev/sda2 clean) so i managed to get to the (TTY) logged in and tried to upgrade, .....FAILED also can't do any of: `autoclean`, `clean`, `--fix-broken` all cuz of the `libglib2.0.0` and `libffi.s.6` also the ubuntu is 20.04 LTS

Comment: I would suggest to force installation of the new library by `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.64.2-1~fakesync1_amd64.deb`. Use auto-completion with <Tab> to enter correct file-name. And then proceed with `sudo apt-get install -f` .

Comment: @N0rbert Dude!, worked like a CHARM thank u so much.

Comment: Great! I added last comment as answer to help other users and have the problem solved (please mark it as accepter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to force installation of the new library by

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.64.2-1~fakesync1_amd64.deb
```

Use auto-completion with <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter correct file-name.

And then proceed with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted suggested solution did not work for me. I got it working by installing libffi6 from bionic deb (since focal only has libffi6) - **This is a hacky workaround and I dont know what else it might break**

Setup:

- Raspberry pi 4
- Ubuntu 20.04 - focal

  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

insert

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
```

then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libffi6
```

it would probably be best that you also delete the deb link from `/etc/apt/sources.list` afterwards